# Calculate mean and sd for given variables in a dataframe

Tags: r, purrr

Given a vector of names of numeric variables in a dataframe, I need to calculate mean and sd for each variable. For example, given the `mtcars` dataset and the following vector of variable names:

```
vars_to_transform <- c("mpg", "disp")
```

I'd like to have the following as result:

[image]

The first solution that came into my mind is the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

data("mtcars")

vars_to_transform <- c("mpg", "disp")

vars_to_transform %>% 
  map_dfr( function(x) { c(variable = x, avg = mean(mtcars[[x]], na.rm = T), sd = sd(mtcars[[x]], na.rm = T)) } )
```

The result is the following:

[image]

As you can see, all the returned variables are characters, but I expected to have numbers for `avg` and `sd`.

Is there a way to fix this? Or is there any better solution than this?

P.S.
I'm using `purr` 0.3.4

Comment: Seems like just about a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/34594641/5325862 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/25955870/5325862 but I don't quite want to flag it as such

Comment: Thank you for notifying it. I didn't found them. Anyway, there are other interesting solution there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like an overcomplicated way of doing `select`->`pivot`->`group`->`summarise`.

```
mtcars %>% 
    select(all_of(vars_to_transform)) %>%
    pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
    group_by(name) %>% 
    summarise(
        mean = mean(value),
        sd = sd(value)
    )
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  name   mean     sd
  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 disp  231.  124.  
2 mpg    20.1   6.03
```

Comment: Nice one! Sometimes the easiest way is hidden from your eyes. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The following works (instead of using `c()` in your code, use `tibble`):

```
vars_to_transform %>% 
  map_dfr(~ tibble(variable = .x, avg = mean(mtcars[[.x]], na.rm = T), 
          sd = sd(mtcars[[.x]], na.rm = T)))
```

**Explanation:** With `c()`, you are using a vector, whose elements *must* have the same type (`character` in your case, because `variable` is `character`). With `tibble`, one can have a different type per element.

@Gwang-Jin Kim suggests, in a comment bellow that I thank, one could also have used `list` instead of `tibble`.

---

Or try with adding `type.convert`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

data("mtcars")

vars_to_transform <- c("mpg", "disp")

vars_to_transform %>% 
  map_dfr( function(x) { c(variable = x, avg = mean(mtcars[[x]], na.rm = T), sd = sd(mtcars[[x]], na.rm = T)) } ) %>% 
  type.convert(as.is=T)

#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   variable   avg     sd
#>   <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 mpg       20.1   6.03
#> 2 disp     231.  124.
```

Comment: I was unaware of `type.convert`. Good to know! But I'm still wondering why all is converted to characters even if for each row avg and sd are calculated correctly as numbers.

Comment: @lucazav: see my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Instread of `tibble` it would suffice to use `list`.

Comment: Thanks, @Gwang-Jin Kim, for letting me know that!

Comment: @PaulSmith welcome! My way of thinking was - because all data frame-like objects in R have lists underlying (list of vectors - each of the vectors constituting each of the columns) - so I guessed, `list` would also work - and it did.

Comment: Perfect logic, @Gwang-Jin Kim!

Comment: @Gwang-Jin Kim: I have just edited my answer, adding your idea of using `list` instead of `tibble`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

vars_to_transform <- c("mpg", "disp")
funs <- lst(mean, sd)

mtcars %>%
  select(all_of(vars_to_transform)) %>%
  map_df(~ funs %>%
           map(exec, .x), .id = "var")

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  var    mean     sd
  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 mpg    20.1   6.03
2 disp  231.  124.
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
m <- mtcars[, vars_to_transform]
tibble(variable = names(m), avg = apply(m, 2, mean), sd = apply(m, 2, sd))

## A tibble: 2 × 3
#  variable   avg     sd
#  <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 mpg       20.1   6.03
#2 disp     231.  124.
```